# How to detect "onload" for base-64 encoded webfonts?

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, onload

How do I access the DOM to detect when my page's webfonts have loaded?

I have 29 .ttf fonts base64-encoded into a single CSS file. I also have a hidden `div` on the page that uses each of the fonts, to make the browser read each of the fonts into memory. That process takes time, so I need to queue an AJAX event to fire after the browser has loaded each of the fonts into memory.

*I know that `document.ready` and `window.onload` get close, but I want to fire the event before the rest of the external resources finish loading to make the AJAX fire sooner.

(jQuery as a last resort, please)

================

**Added Sample Code:**

**HTML**

```
<head>
...
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="TTF-embedded-fonts.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="load-fonts.js"></script>
</head>
```

**load-fonts.js**

```
var ST1 = document.createElement('div');
ST1.setAttribute('id', 'fontloader');
ST1.innerHTML = "<span style='font-family:samplefont'>a<b>b<i>c</i></b><i>d</i></span> ... ";
ST1.style.cssText = "height:0px;text-indent:-9999px;visibility:hidden";

window.document.body.onload = appendST1 ();
function appendST1() { document.body.appendChild(ST1) };

[FONT-LOAD HANDLER HERE] { API.Ajax.loadComplete("load-fonts.js") };
```

**TTF-embedded-fonts.css**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'samplefont';
    src: url(data:font/truetype;charset=utf-8;base64,AAAE...) format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'samplefont';
    src: url(data:font/truetype;charset=utf-8;base64,AAAE...) format('truetype');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'samplefont';
    src: url(data:font/truetype;charset=utf-8;base64,AAAE...) format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'samplefont';
    src: url(data:font/truetype;charset=utf-8;base64,AAAE...) format('truetype');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Comment: Got an example of what you mean?

Comment: @James - I posted a copy of what I'm working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google's WebFont Loader](http://code.google.com/apis/webfonts/docs/webfont_loader.html) solves this problem. Use the [custom module](http://code.google.com/apis/webfonts/docs/webfont_loader.html#Specifying) to load the CSS, and then use any of the [six javascript callback events](http://code.google.com/apis/webfonts/docs/webfont_loader.html#Events) to signal when the fonts have loaded and/or failed to load.

I have tested this method.  It works for base64 encoded fonts and regularly linked fonts.

*For non-javscript fallback, make sure to include a duplicate link to the CSS stylesheet in the HTML when using the Google WebFont Loader.

Answer (score 0):

To start I would comment out the `ST1.style.cssText = "height:0px;text-indent:-9999px;visibility:hidden";` line to make sure it is getting written to the page properly.

Assuming that works a solution (although probably not the best) is to add a `<script>` tag after the `<span>` tag.

```
"<span style='font-family:samplefont'>1a<b>b<i>c</i></b><i>d</i></span>"
+ "<scrip" + "t type=\"text/javascr" + "ipt\">\n" 
+ "Code Goes here" 
+ "\n</scri" + "pt>"
```

And I would add it via jQuery if you have it:

```
var ST1 = $("<div><span style='font-family:samplefont'>1a<b>b<i>c</i></b><i>d</i></span><scrip" 
+ "t type=\"text/javascr" + "ipt\">\n" 
+ "Code Goes here" 
+ "\n</scri" + "pt></div>");
$(document.body).append(ST1);
```